# iPhone/xCode Done Toolbar Keyboard Accessory Class

Tags: ios, toolbar

I am trying to create a class that can I can call to easily implement a done toolbar.

Currently I am calling it like this,

```
    -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       DoneToolbar *tlbDone = [[DoneToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
       [textField setInputAccessoryView:tlbDone];
    }
```

This works to bring up the Toolbar, however the issue comes with the Done button,

Currently I am trying to do this by the following code,

```
#import "DoneToolbar.h"

@implementation DoneToolbar
@synthesize btnDone;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        //Done Button
        UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(btnDonePressed)];
        UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
        NSArray *barItemArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexible,doneBarButton, nil];
        self.items = barItemArr;
        [self.superview endEditing:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)btnDonePressed{
        [self.superview endEditing:YES];
}

@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call `endEditing:` on the view with the 1st responder. That isn't going to be `self.superview`.

Comment: BTW - why do you wait to set the text field's inputView when it already started editing? You should set it when you create the text field.

Comment: Normally, if I was calling it in the class I am setting the Keyboard accessory and not Toolbar class I would do: [self.view endEditing:YES]; on the Done button press. I don't know how to obtain self.view from the toolbar class. Also I am setting it when the keyboard begins editing because the UiTextFeilds are created in an XIB file